# How do you determine when an angularjs $service has finished its work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the `$location` service inside my controller to enable deep linking. My controller does something like this:

```
$location.path("/"+param);
$("title").text(param);
```

It's critical that the second line finishes executing after the first. Otherwise the history item inside the browser will show the new title for the old url instead of the old one. Google.com currently has this error, try a search from the homepage, and then another search, and then hold down the back button in your browser and press on the most recent history item, you'll see what I mean.

One way to fix this is:

```
$location.path("/"+param);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("title").text(param);
}, 1);
```

...but that just doesn't sit too well with me. So my question is how do I defer the second line's execution robustly once the `$location` singleton has finished its own business?

Comment: The `$location.path` should take a callback function if it functions like this.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, which browser are you using ?
Although I agree that, this async behavior is weird. I think we might change that, need to think about it bit more...

Comment: @Vojta I tested on Safari and Chrome. I've rearchitected my app slightly by creating a state manager service which handles the url routing and controller lifecycle as the user navigates my app. So I can write dumb controllers which just notify the state manager when they are about to cause a state change (e.g. when they load a new view+controller in using ng-include), and it then sorts out the arbitrarily deep controller stack and notifies the relevant controllers of the state changed so they can then initialise themselves and set the title amongst other things...

Comment: @Vojta ... This approach lets me create a complex nested view+controller hierarchy implemented using simple, Law of Demeter abiding controllers that are only responsible for managing their own little subview and are totally unaware of the entire view hierarchy or the app's overall state. Controllers don't need to worry about deep-linking, it just works. And the app is idempotent so I avoid the problem in the original question entirely.

Comment: Awesome, that sounds way better.

Btw, you could use binding for setting the title:
`<title ng-bind="title">Default title before set</title>`

And particular controller only sets the title.

Be sure to check out $route + ng-view as well, it sounds like you might use that.

Comment: @Vojta I originally looked at $route but it doesn't support nested views, so I rolled my own service.

Comment: Currently there can be only one ng-view on a single page. But you can use ng-include to do nested views... Of course, if even this doesn't fit your needs, write your custom one...

Answer (score 0):

[AngularJS: Using $location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

> Note that the setters don't update window.location immediately. Instead, $location service is aware of the scope life-cycle and coalesces multiple $location mutations into one "commit" to the window.location object during the scope $digest phase.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a methodology that fits async services in general (??). It seems to me that you would want to look at the promise/deferred implementation see  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

> "At first it might not be obvious why this extra complexity is worth the trouble. The payoff comes in the way of guarantees that promise and deferred apis make."

hope this helps

--dan